# OGR Split a vector layer by attributes

Tags: python, ogr

With a `Python` script, I want to split a vector layer by attributes. For each unique value of a define field, I want to create a new layer with a name that contains this attribute in camelCase and with features concerned. I divide my logic in three steps :

1. Iterate throught my source layer to find every unique value of my field of interest (*city_code*).
2. Create each necessary new layer, with the good name (*city_name* in camelCase).
3. Insert values in this respectives layers.

`OGR` give me good results for steps 1 and 2, but I can't achieve step 3. I can't iterate a second time in my features and insert values in corresponding layers I've created in step 2. Maybe my logic is wrong.

[Documentation](https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/vector_layers.html#iterate-over-features) says "*You must call ResetReading if you want to start iterating over the layer again.*", perfect for my purpose but I'm not able to apply this.

What the best way to split a vector layer by attributes with `OGR` ?

**Data** *(parcel.shp)*

```
id | city_name | city_code
--------------------------
1  | New-York  | 001
2  | New-York  | 001
3  | New-York  | 001
4  | Toronto   | 002
5  | Toronto   | 002
6  | Toronto   | 002
7  | Seattle   | 003
8  | Seattle   | 003
9  | Seattle   | 003
```

**Script**

```
from osgeo import ogr
from collections import OrderedDict

# Input
file = r"parcel"
inputFolder = r"C:/Users/me/myFolder/"
outputFolder = r"C:/Users/me/myFolder/shapes/"

# Layer
extension = r".shp"
inputFile = inputFolder + file + extension
driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')
dataSource = driver.Open(inputFile)
layer = dataSource.GetLayer()
spatialReference = layer.GetSpatialRef()

# Step 1

# List by attributes
listeCityCode = []
for feat in layer:
    cityCode = feat.GetField("city_code")
    listeCityCode.append(cityCode)    

listeCityCodeUnique = set(listeCityCode)
listeCityCodeUniqueOrdered = list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(listeCityCodeUnique))

# Selection by city_code
index = 0
for i in listeCityCodeUniqueOrdered:    
    sql = f'SELECT * FROM {file} WHERE city_code LIKE \'{listeCityCodeUniqueOrdered[index]}\''
    index += 1
    layerQuery = dataSource.ExecuteSQL(sql)

    # Get fields    
    for feature in layerQuery :
        id = feature.GetField("id")
        city_name = feature.GetField("city_name")
        city_code = feature.GetField("city_code")
        geom = feature.GetGeometryRef()

    # City name in camelCase
    c0 = str(city_name)
    c1 = c0.replace("-"," ")
    c2 = c1.title()
    city_name_camelCase = c2.replace(" ","")

    # Step 2

    # Create a layer by city name       
    newDataSource = driver.CreateDataSource(r"{}parcel_{}_{}.shp".format(outputFolder, city_code, city_name_camelCase))
    newLayer = newDataSource.CreateLayer("parcel_{}_{}".format(city_code, city_name_camelCase), spatialReference, ogr.wkbPolygon) 

    # Create fields
    newLayer.CreateField(ogr.FieldDefn("id", ogr.OFTInteger))
    field_city_name = ogr.FieldDefn("city_name", ogr.OFTString)
    field_city_name.SetWidth(50)
    newLayer.CreateField(field_city_name)
    field_city_code = ogr.FieldDefn("city_code", ogr.OFTString)
    field_city_code.SetWidth(10)
    newLayer.CreateField(field_city_code) 

    # Step 3

    for feature in layerQuery:         

        newFeature = ogr.Feature(newLayer.GetLayerDefn())

        newFeature.SetField("id", id)
        newFeature.SetField("city_name", city_name)
        newFeature.SetField("city_code", code_code)
        newFeature.SetGeometry(geom)           

        newLayer.CreateFeature(newFeature)

        del newDataSource, newLayer
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a feedback, because I found a way to execute my problem. One of the important difficulties here is to create layers without knowing the name in advance. So I split the creation of layers and the insertion of elements into them in 2 steps. Another important point is the opening and closing of data sources. And also the read or writing mode when opening a layer.

Here is a full script, with user feedbacks :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from osgeo import ogr
from collections import OrderedDict
import glob
import os

# Input settings
myFile = r"parcel"
inputFolder = r"C:/Users/me/myFolder/"
outputFolder = r"C:/Users/me/myFolder/mySubFolder/"

# Source layer
extension = r".shp"
inputFile = inputFolder + myFile + extension
driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')
dataSource = driver.Open(inputFile)
layer = dataSource.GetLayer()
spatialReference = layer.GetSpatialRef()

print(f"---- Beginning of process ----\n\nLayer analysis :\n{myFile}{extension}")

# Step 1 : List of city codes in source layer
listCityCode = []
for feat in layer:
    cityCode = feat.GetField("city_code")
    listCityCode.append(cityCode)    

listCityCodeUnique = set(listCityCode)
listCityCodeUniqueOrdered = list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(listCityCodeUnique))
numberCityCode = len(listCityCodeUniqueOrdered)

print(f"|-> {numberCityCode} city codes found\n\nWork in progress, please wait...")

# Step 2 : create a shapefile by city code

# Selection of city code in source layer
index = 0
for i in listCityCodeUniqueOrdered:    
    sql = f'SELECT * FROM {myFile} WHERE city_code LIKE \'{listCityCodeUniqueOrdered[index]}\''
    index += 1
    layerQuery = dataSource.ExecuteSQL(sql)

    # Get attributes    
    for feature in layerQuery :        
        city_name = feature.GetField("city_name")
        city_code = feature.GetField("city_code")

    # CamelCase and specials characters (especially for non-English languages)
    c0 = str(city_name)
    c1 = c0.replace("-"," ").replace("'"," ").replace("à","a").replace("â","a").replace("ä","a").replace("é","e").replace("è","e").replace("ë","e").replace("ê","e").replace("í","i").replace("ì","i").replace("ï","i").replace("î","i").replace("ô","o").replace("ö","o").replace("ó","o").replace("ò","o").replace("ú","u").replace("ù","u").replace("û","u").replace("ü","u").replace("æ","ae").replace("œ","oe").replace("ç","c").replace("ñ","n")
    c2 = c1.title().replace("À","A").replace("Â","A").replace("Ä","A").replace("É","E").replace("È","E").replace("Ê","E").replace("Ë","E").replace("Í","I").replace("Ì","I").replace("Ï","I").replace("Î","I").replace("Ô","O").replace("Ö","O").replace("Ó","O").replace("Ò","O").replace("Ú","U").replace("Ù","U").replace("Û","U").replace("Ü","U").replace("Æ","Ae").replace("Œ","Oe").replace("Ç","C").replace("Ñ","N")
    city_name_camelCase = c2.replace(" ","")

    # Create a layer by city code        
    newDataSource = driver.CreateDataSource(r"{}parcel_{}_{}.shp".format(outputFolder, city_code, city_name_camelCase))
    newLayer = newDataSource.CreateLayer("{}parcel_{}_{}".format(outputFolder, city_code, city_name_camelCase), spatialReference, ogr.wkbPolygon) 

    # Create fields
    field_id = ogr.FieldDefn("id", ogr.OFTString)
    field_id.SetWidth(14)
    newLayer.CreateField(field_id) 
    field_city_name = ogr.FieldDefn("city_name", ogr.OFTString)
    field_city_name.SetWidth(45)
    newLayer.CreateField(field_city_name)
    field_city_code = ogr.FieldDefn("city_code", ogr.OFTString)
    field_city_code.SetWidth(3)
    newLayer.CreateField(field_city_code)

    # Dereference the feature
    newFeature = None

# Dereference source
newDataSource = None

print(f"\nCreating .shp :\n")

# Step 3 : insert features in respectives cities layers

# List of layers create by city codes
os.chdir(outputFolder)
indexFile = 0
for i, file in enumerate(glob.glob("*.shp")):
    indexFile += 1
    currentDataSource = file
    currentLayer = file[0:-4]
    currentCodeCom = file[10:13]    

    # Open each communal layer in writing mode
    fileCommunal = f"{currentLayer}"
    inputFileCommunal = outputFolder + fileCommunal + extension
    dataSourceCommunal = driver.Open(inputFileCommunal, 1) # 0 read-only, 1 write
    layerCommunal = dataSourceCommunal.GetLayer()

    # Selection by city code in source layer
    sqlCommunal = f'SELECT * FROM {myFile} WHERE city_code LIKE \'{currentCodeCom}\''
    layerQueryCommunal = dataSource.ExecuteSQL(sqlCommunal)

    # Get attributes
    for feature in layerQueryCommunal :
        id = feature.GetField("id")        
        city_name = feature.GetField("city_name")
        city_code = feature.GetField("city_code")
        geom = feature.GetGeometryRef()

        # Create a new feature
        newFeatureCommunal = ogr.Feature(layerCommunal.GetLayerDefn())

        # Insert values
        newFeatureCommunal.SetField("id", id)        
        newFeatureCommunal.SetField("city_name", city_name)
        newFeatureCommunal.SetField("city_code", city_code)
        newFeatureCommunal.SetGeometry(geom)        

        # Insertfeature
        layerCommunal.CreateFeature(newFeatureCommunal)

        # Dereference the feature
        newFeatureCommunal = None

    # Dereference source
    dataSourceCommunal = None

    print(f"{indexFile}/{numberCityCode} - {file}")

print(f"\n{indexFile} layer created\n\n---- End of process ----")
```

Maybe this method may not be the best, in a Pythonic and syntactic point of view. Using functions could be a better way. If someone has better to offer, I am interested, especially in terms of performance and execution time (which is a big deal with layers containing a lot of features).